# Dynamic angular chart

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a dynamic chart from userTemplate object.
I'm using this directive [angular-flot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-flot) and I want create the dataset and options of directive dynamically.
Its work but I have this error

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3…ection%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22color%5C%22%3A%5C%22%2354728c%5C%22%7D%7D%22%5D%5D
    at Error (native)
    at http://mwm3-gui/asset/script/vendor/angular2.1/angular.min.js:6:450
    at k.$get.k.$digest (http://mwm3-gui/asset/script/vendor/angular2.1/angular.min.js:110:66)
    at k.$get.k.$apply (http://mwm3-gui/asset/script/vendor/angular2.1/angular.min.js:112:173)
    at http://mwm3-gui/asset/script/vendor/angular2.1/angular.min.js:122:253
    at e (http://mwm3-gui/asset/script/vendor/angular2.1/angular.min.js:37:440)
    at http://mwm3-gui/asset/script/vendor/angular2.1/angular.min.js:41:120
```

HTML

```
<div  ng-repeat="panel in row.panels" class="{{panel.columnClass}}" resizable id="{{panel.id}}" r-directions="['right']">
     <flot dataset="getDataForChart(panel)" options="getOptionForChart(panel)"  height="{{panel.graph.height}}"></flot>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
$scope.userTemplate = [
                        {
                            blockId: 'blockUno',
                            title: 'Block title',
                            rows: [
                                {
                                    rowId: 'rowUno',
                                    title: 'Row Title 1',
                                    panels: [
                                        {
                                            id: 'palel-report-1',
                                            title: 'uno',
                                            columnClass: 'col-md-4',
                                            graph: {
                                                height: 250,
                                                type: "BAR",
                                                countBy: "status"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            id: 'palel-report-2',
                                            title: 'due',
                                            columnClass: 'col-md-4',
                                            graph: {
                                                height: 250,
                                                type: "PIE",
                                                countBy: "status"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            id: 'palel-report-3',
                                            title: 'tre',
                                            columnClass: 'col-md-4',
                                            graph: {
                                                height: 250,
                                                type: "BAR",
                                                countBy: "status"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            tables: []
                        }
    ];

    $scope.getDataForChart = function(panel) {
      var graphData = [];
      var countBy = panel.graph.countBy;
      var arr = $scope.reportingData;
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          var valueOfkey = arr[i][countBy];
          graphData.push(valueOfkey);
      }
      var a = [], b = [], prev;
      graphData.sort();
      for (var i = 0; i < graphData.length; i++) {
          if (graphData[i] !== prev) {
              a.push(graphData[i]);
              b.push(1);
           } else {
              b[b.length - 1]++;
           }
           prev = graphData[i];
         }

        var graphData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
          var singleO = {label: '' + a[i], data: [[i, b[i]]]};
          graphData.push(singleO);
        }
        return graphData;
    };

    $scope.getOptionForChart = function(panel) {
        var options = angular.copy($scope.defaultPlotOptions);
        var typeGraph = panel.graph.type;
        switch (typeGraph) {
            case "BAR":
            options.series.bars.show = true;
            break;
            case "LINE":
            options.series.lines.show = true;
            break;
            case "PIE":
            options.series.pie.show = true;
            break;
            case "POINT":
            options.series.points.show = true;
            break;
            case "TABLE":
            break;
        }
        return options;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is from an infinite digest loop.

In a couple of places you are calling functions that return new items each time. Here's an example from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=undefined) linked from the error message you received that suggests this may cause this error:

> One common mistake is binding to a function which generates a new
>   array every time it is called. For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in getUsers()">{{ user.name }}</div>

$scope.getUsers = function() {   return [ { name: 'Hank' }, { name: 'Francisco' } ]; };
```

> Since getUsers() returns a new array, Angular
>   determines that the model is different on each $digest cycle,
>   resulting in the error. The solution is to return the same array
>   object if the elements have not changed:

```
var users = [ { name: 'Hank' }, { name: 'Francisco' } ];

$scope.getUsers = function() {   return users; };
```

In your code, you are doing the same binding to `getDataForChart` and `getOptionForChart`.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure that I have understood the solution that you proposed.

Comment: Do you see the similarity to the documented example? You are doing the same with your graph data by creating it each time in the function.

Comment: So a solution would be to declare it outside of the function

Comment: @user3790694 You should delete your answer, it's more of just a comment on mine than an actual answer. To solve your new issue, you could include the data and options as a part of each panel in your initial data. Then proceed to pass in the panel and operate on it's options/data just as you did initially except you will be modifying your existing data structure instead of creating items on the fly. Does that make sense? So you will end up with panel.graphData and panel.options.